# Navigation to the webpage was cancelled - ASP.NET & ABC PDF

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, abcpdf, windows-server-2008-x64

I am moving my application from IIS 6.0/Windows Server 2003 to IIS 7.5/Windows Server 2008 R2 and it use the WebSuperGoo ABCpdf control to convert web pages into printable PDFs.

When I browse to the page that converts the webpage to a PDF, it generates a PDF of a "Navigation to the web was cancelled" error page.

I am using the 8.1.0.9 version of the ABCpdf and changed the namespace in the page from `WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7` to `WebSupergoo.ABCpdf`.

Has anyone expected this issue and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have abandoned ABC PDF all together and replaced it with [Winnovative HTML to PDF Convertor for .NET](http://www.winnovative-software.com/Html-To-Pdf-Converter.aspx)

We renewed our redistributable license because another developer within our company was using an older version and mentioned it would be a good replacement for ABC PDF.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same error and my co-worker had an immediate answer.
In my case it was that the website was protected with a password by IIS.

ABCpdf does not know how to enter credential information so it won't work if the page is asking for username/password.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be that the server cant see the website URL. this is normal on production servers running a NAT. 
Just change the hostfile on the server to allow the domain to resolve.